# Diffrence between assigning simple prototype and using Object.Create(Object.prototype) in protypal inheritence in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am implementing Prototypal inheritence in java script using simple assigning of prototype this is my code -

```
var Rectangle = function(heigth, width) {
  this.height = height;
  this.width  = width;  
}

Rectangle.prototype.area = function() {
  return this.height*this.width;
}

var Square = function(length) {
  this.height = this.width = length;
}

Square.prototype = Rectangle.prototype; 

var sqr1 = new Square(5);
console.log(sqr1.area());
```

But at the place of **Square.prototype = Rectangle.prototype** it is recommended to use  **Square.prototype = Object.create(Rectangle.prototype)**. Can anyone tell me the underlying difference because the above code is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Because the statement `Square.prototype = Rectangle.prototype;` actually copies the reference of the `Rectangle.prototype` and assigns it to `Square.prototype`. (Primitive types are copied by value and reference types are copied by reference).

So, if you are going to add some properties and methods on `Square.prototype` it'll modify the original `Rectangle.prototype` object and which is not what you want.

The `Square.prototype = Object.create(Rectangle.prototype)` creates a new `object` whose prototype is the `Rectangle.prototype` which is correct way.