# How can one use this code in personal projects? what does it do exactly for you

Tags: javascript, inheritance, namespaces, ecmascript-5

I've been having issues with the structure of my vanilla js code, with regards to
local/global variables/methods, inheritance, etc.

my search for a good example of code found this script:markerwithlabel.js

im curious about this bit:

```
/**
 * @param {Function} childCtor Child class.
 * @param {Function} parentCtor Parent class.
 * @private
 */
function inherits(childCtor, parentCtor) {
  /* @constructor */
  function tempCtor() {}
  tempCtor.prototype = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.superClass_ = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.prototype = new tempCtor();
  /* @override */
  childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor;
}
```

source: https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/packages/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js

How can one use this code in personal projects? what does it do exactly for you.

apparently this snippet is widely used:
https://github.com/search?p=5&q=%22function+inherits%28childCtor%2C+parentCtor%29+%7B%22&type=Code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Diffrence between assigning simple prototype and using Object.Create(Object.prototype) in protypal inheritence in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944854/diffrence-between-assigning-simple-prototype-and-using-object-createobject-prot)

Answer (score 1):

This is the prototypal way of performing inheritance in javascript. This function `inherits(childCtor, parentCtor)` simply passes properties and features from `parentCtor` to `childCtor`. It's an object oriented principle of sharing features between related objects. This code does exactly what `extends` in es2015 does in objects. Please refer to my comments below, I tried to be open and not more technical.

```
function inherits(childCtor, parentCtor) 
{
  // This declares a function to be used as a constructor for childCtor
  function tempCtor() {}
      // This copies the prototype of the parent to the temporary class which is thechild, 
      // remember that the parent's prototype has properties that the child is inheriting
      tempCtor.prototype = parentCtor.prototype;
      // this adds a property called superClass inside child object that informs it who the parent is. so when you access that property it will refer to the parent
      childCtor.superClass_ = parentCtor.prototype;
      // This is where the new instance of child object is created through using tempCtor as the basis because all data was stored in it.
      childCtor.prototype = new tempCtor();

  // this then informs the childCtor that the method called constructor refers to itself
  childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor;
}
```

I just wanted to make it quick, You can read further more on this topic [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Comment: the MDN article was awesome

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Javascript is a great language.